# Time promise requests to an API using setInterval or setTimeout

Tags: api, promise, setinterval

I have this issue - I'm trying to fetch a data from a constant url that accepts an integer ID.

I have these integers stacked in array.
I do not want to flood the server with requests so I tried using setInterval and setTimeout to time the requests.

I did take in consideration that a promise might take some time to complete but couldn't figure out how to explicitly apply that.

The results of this code are just:
"[] 1"

```js
const axios = require('axios')
const dataFile = require('../data/car_data')

const modelNameUrl = 'https://www.gov.il/api/mot/carlistprice/api/modelName?yazran_id='

const carId = dataFile.map(data => data.manufacturer_id)

const fetch = async (id) => {
    const dataFetched = await axios.get(`${modelNameUrl}${id}`).then()
    return dataFetched.data.dgamim_yazran
}

let index = 0
setInterval(async () => {
    const data = await fetch(index)
    index++
    console.log(data, index)
}, 10000)
```

Additional code for further debugging:

```js
const axios = require('axios')
// const dataFile = require('../data/car_data')
// dataFile.map(data => data.manufacturer_id)

const modelNameUrl = 'https://www.gov.il/api/mot/carlistprice/api/modelName?yazran_id='

let dataArray = []

const fetch = async (id) => {
    const dataFetched = await axios.get(`${modelNameUrl}${id}`)
    return dataFetched.data.dgamim_yazran
}
function delay(t) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, t));
}
let integerSource = [
    6, 67, 4, 5, 9, 60, 7, 30, 107, 113, 19,
    120, 15, 17, 12, 59, 3, 129, 56, 1, 124, 29,
    26, 64, 33, 63, 131, 112, 2, 39, 133, 38, 40,
    48, 52, 53, 54, 50, 13, 110, 51, 57, 68, 23,
    44, 22, 41, 21, 10, 32, 47, 45, 11
]

async function runLoop() {
    for (let index of integerSource) {
        try {
            const data = await fetch(index);
            console.log(data, index);
            await delay(5000);
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(`Error on index ${index}`, e);
            throw new Error
        }
    }
}

runLoop().then(() => {
    console.log("all done");
}).catch(err => {
    console.log("ended with error\n", err);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest just using a `for` loop with `await` and then a promise-returning delay.  This will space out your API calls from when they finish, not from when they started.  Your existing scheme does not increment the index right away so it could even make duplicate calls to `fetch()`.

You say you have the desired integers stack in an array, but don't show that in your code.  You can either use a `for` loop that just increments an index or you can use the `for` loop to pull integers from your array.

```
function delay(t) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, t));
}

let integerSource = [...];    // your array of integer values

async function runLoop() {
    for (let index of integerSource) {
        try {
            const data = await fetch(index);
            conole.log(data, index);
            await delay(10000);
        } catch(e) {
            conole.log(`Error on index ${index}`, e);
            // decide here whether you continue with further requests
            // or throw e to stop further processing                
        }
    }
}

// run the loop here
runLoop().then(() => {
   console.log("all done");
}).catch(err => {
   console.log("ended with error");
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  I want to learn from you answer.
Basically it is better to create a timer, promise-based one so we cant await it.
We need that in order to wait a certain time between calls, otherwise this doesn't work consistantly or at all. am I right?
After we get a promise based function, and create an async function to get the data (also wrap it within try&catch to catch any error not before we implement the delay function within the fetch function and await aswell.

Comment: hi, actually I cannot because I don't have enough reputation to do so, I wish :)

Comment: the resolve argument while declaring the Promise is there for? an empty or useless filler?

Comment: @arielah - The `resolve` argument is passed to `setTimeout()`.

Comment: oh got you, I just saw that!
I tested it out and got a single response, and it just seems that the program doesn't continue to the next id in the array

Comment: Well, your code sets the delay to 10 seconds so that's what I used also.  Did you wait long enough?  Are you defining an array of multiple numbers for `integerSource`?  We can't really help you debug code we can't see.

Comment: Yeah I did, I also changed it to 2 seconds just to make sure. I will edit the initial message of this topic in a moment with the code so you can understand it better, thank you for your help again!

Comment: @arielah - Also, change this `await axios.get(\`${modelNameUrl}${id}\`).then()` to `await axios.get(\`${modelNameUrl}${id}\`);`.  There's shouldn't ever be an empty `.then()`.

Comment: @arielah - Don't change the original question at all.  Leave all that there.  That question needs to match what I supplied an answer to.  You can ADD new code to the end of the question for further debugging.

Comment: Added at the end of the message for further debugging. That`s how you meant for it to be?

Comment: @arielah - That API has some "botMitigation" detection in it and you aren't getting past that.  If you look at the response from the first request, you will see a cookie with `BotMitigationCookie` in the cookie value.  It will take some detective work to figure out how to get around that.

Comment: you're awsome! thats sad to hear because I only need the data from that api only once so I can turn it into a local json file.
Thanks for all the help jfriend00